# Strange error at super.onStart();

Tags: java, android, mysql, super

I developed an Android application and it runs perfectly but sometimes it throws a strange error:

If the application had been executed before and you execute it again, just sometimes, it throws me the next error: `android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0`.

The strange part of this (at least for me, cause I'm not an Android expert) is that, apart of that this doesn't occurs always, is that the first point appearing at the error log is the`super.onStart();` line of my main.java and I don't have nothing before that line.

Here is my onStart method:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);

    mPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());
}
```

Here is the error log:

```
...
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:418)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getInt(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:68)
    at mysql.BaseDatos.getAsignaturaDataBase(BaseDatos.java:233)
    at com.tfd.myapp.FragmentAsig.onCreateView(FragmentAsig.java:269)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1877)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:552)
    at com.tfd.myapp.Principal.onStart(Principal.java:108)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1166)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5254)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2043)
...
```

How this can be possible?

Comment: Which activity class do you extend?

Comment: Not sure if this helps you: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#L1160 Have you ever got the chance to debug such a crash? Or does it only happen in non-debug mode? :)

Comment: If you have a cursor in your super class, check if it having any data, before using the cursor object.

if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
       // if cursor contains data, the first object; then do your job here
}

Comment: Your error happens inside FragmentAsig, inside onCreateView. Make sure your cursor is not null and it has elements as @vembutech described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onStart()` executes any pending fragment transactions. In this case it involves instantiating your `FragmentAsig` and the bug is there. Specifically:

```
at mysql.BaseDatos.getAsignaturaDataBase(BaseDatos.java:233)
at com.tfd.myapp.FragmentAsig.onCreateView(FragmentAsig.java:269)
```

you're calling `getInt()` on a `Cursor` that has no data. You need to check that e.g. `moveToFirst()` succeeded.